# here we know that deque is an interface and queue is also an interface so deque should implement queue but here it is extending it?

Tags: java, arrays, json, collections

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbNhq.jpg)

[https://www.javatpoint.com/collections-in-java#:~:text=The%20Collection%20in%20Java%20is%20a%20framework%20that,Java%20Collection%20means%20a%20single%20unit%20of%20objects.](https://www.javatpoint.com/collections-in-java#:%7E:text=The%20Collection%20in%20Java%20is%20a%20framework%20that,Java%20Collection%20means%20a%20single%20unit%20of%20objects.)

Comment: Classes implement interfaces. Interfaces extend interfaces.

Comment: Please enter your question directly instead of linking to it. I'm not clicking those links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class implements an interface. An interface may extend from another interface, but cannot implement.

*Implementing* means providing the content, the state and behavior, of a class as required to meet the contract defined in the interface. An interface has neither state nor behavior, only method signatures. (We are ignoring `default` methods on an interface as they are but a hack needed for lambdas/streams support.)

➥ Study the [tutorial on interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html) provided free of cost by Oracle.